# Git post-receive hook is throwing errow

Tags: git

**Background:**

I set post-receive hook on my server bare repo

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 midnight midnight   58 Jan 24 19:45 post-receive

$ cat post-receive 
GIT_WORK_TREE = /var/www/mongo_conprima git checkout -f
file permission of /var/www/mongo_conprima

drwxr-xr-x  3 midnight midnight     4096 Jan 25 08:40 mongo_conprima
```

Porblem I get following error when I push from local host

```
    Counting objects: 3, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 228 bytes, done.
    Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: hooks/post-receive: 1: hooks/post-receive: GIT_WORK_TREE: not found
```

I want to update production directory after each push on server [question]:git hook to update changes to working directory and bare git directory

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignments in shell scripts don't allow whitespace before the equal sign. Change to:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mongo_conprima git checkout -f
```